# How do I control the list of certificates presented when digitally signing Excel VBA code?

Tags: vba, excel, certificate, digital-certificate

**Summary:**

My goal is to digitally sign my Excel VBA macros using a government-issued (hardware/physical) certificate. I know how to accomplish the task from the VBA Code window, but the certificate I want isn't presented. I know that the certificate is available to Windows and to Excel. How can I identify what logic Excel uses to decide which certificates to present for digitally signing code?

**Details:**

(1) I want to digitally sign my code as follows: Developer menu -> View Code button -> (opens VBA Code window) -> Tools menu -> Digital Signature menu item -> Choose button -> (displays a list of available certificates). Unfortunately, I only see software-based certificates, not the hardware-based one that I need to sign this macro with.

(2) I know that the hardware certificate is available to Windows and my browsers, because I can use it to sign in to various websites using IE11, Chrome, and Firefox. I also know that the certificate is available to Office, because I can use it to digitally sign the workbook itself (from the main Excel window, Insert tab -> Signature Line button -> Microsoft Office Signature Line... option -> (opens Signature Setup dialog) -> OK button -> (double-click in the signature field that is placed in the workbook -> Change... button -> (displays a list of certificates, INCLUDING the one that I want).

(3) I have Administrative permissions on the computer. I have checked in certmgr.msc that the certificate is available to Windows (it's listed in Certificates - Current User -> Personal -> Certificates), that it's not expired, and that it has a valid trust chain to a Certificate Authority (CA) in my trust store (as listed in Certificates - Current User -> Trusted Root Certification Authorities -> Certificates).

(4) I have Googled this issue to no end, but can only get the standard "this is how you digitally sign your code" pages, without finding references to what to do if the certificate you want isn't listed. I even called Microsoft Support, but because it was related to VBA, they wouldn't help me (even though my company has a corporate license and a support contract for application issues).

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Both the workbook and code signature procedures list the certificates filed under "Personal" tab in IE. My guess is that your certificate isn't intented for code signing. In the certificate's Details tab, look for the Enhanced Key Usage field; does it say "Code Signing"?

Comment: No, nothing that says Code Signing. I have three certificates that trace to that hard token. #1 has Intended Purpose = <All> and no Enhanced Key Usage property. #2 has Intended Purpose = Smart Card Logon, Client Authentication, Secure Email and Enhanced Key Usage showing those 3 as well. #3 has Intended Purpose = Smart Card Logon, Client Authentication and Enhanced Key Usage showing those 2 as well. I'm unable to add purposes to the two that aren't <All> (no surprises there, I suppose)...presumably that is something the card issuer would have to do? Curious that #1 (<All>) doesn't show.